# Automate command execution in PuTTY fails with "Not able to find file"

Tags: putty

1. I gave the below thing from the command prompt and it opened the PuTTY:

   ```
   putty.exe abc@1.1.1.1 22 -pw 1234
   ```
2. I would like to execute another command so I used the below command:

   ```
   putty.exe abc@1.1.1.1 22 -pw 1234 -m C:\users\vid.txt
   ```

   In vid.txt I mentioned the command (for tunneling).
3. The Putty window opens and immediately closes, not sure whether the command in the vid.txt is executed or not. Can you advise here how to keep the putty open even after executing the command from vid.txt

I'm new to PuTTY. Can you please suggest a solution or an easy way of handling it?

Comment: It sounds like PuTTY is unable to find the file `C:\users\vid.txt`, are you sure it exists on your computer and not mistyped, I would expect something like `C:\users\vid\vid.txt`?

Comment: @heavyd PuTTY says *"unable to open command file ..."* when it cannot find the file specified by `-m` switch. - @vid Is the message exactly *"Not able to find file"*?

Answer (score 0):

With `-m` switch, PuTTY uses a non-interactive session by default.

Your command/script probably relies on some environment variables (like `PATH`) being set specifically.

It's quite probable that the variables are set only for interactive sessions. Probably because they are modified in a startup script that is executed (sourced) for the the interactive sessions only.

Solutions are:

- Correct the startup scripts to modify the variables unconditionally (even for non-interactive sessions).
- Modify the script not to rely on environment variables.

  Or you can source the profile script, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44847506/850848.
- Force the PuTTY to use an interactive session using the [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty")